# Same data is set on each position in RecyclerView when adapter is notified for data change after fetching data from JSON

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I'm fetching data from a database and getting JSON correctly. Also, when I set adapter on the RecyclerView, everything seems to work fine except that same data is set on each position, however I get the complete ArrayList with 20 different values. I don't know where I'm messing up with notifyDatasetChanged as it's the first time I'm using the RecyclerView.

I'm using a fragment inside an activity and here in the codes, I've used Log statements(I used "############" instead of LOG_TAG, *though*) which tells me that complete arraylist of 20 movie details is available when the onBindViewHolder is called.

Here are the codes:

**DefaultMovieFragment.java**

```
public class DefaultMovieFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<Movie>> {

private static final int DEFAULT_MOVIE_LOADER_ID = 1;
ArrayList<Movie> movies;
DefaultMovieAdapter mAdapter;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

public DefaultMovieFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v("############", "onCreateView called");
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_default_movie, container, false);
    Movie movie = new Movie("ram", 2, "path");
    if (savedInstanceState==null){
        movies = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    //First of all check if network is connected or not then only start the loader
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

      /* fetch data. Get a reference to the LoaderManager, in order to interact with loaders. */
        startLoaderManager();
        Log.v("############", "startLoaderManager called");
    }

    // Lookup the recyclerview in activity layout
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewMovies);

    // Create mAdapter passing in the sample user data
    mAdapter = new DefaultMovieAdapter(getActivity(), movies);
    // Attach the mAdapter to the recyclerview to populate items
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // First param is number of columns and second param is orientation i.e Vertical or Horizontal
    final StaggeredGridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager =
            new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    // Attach the layout manager to the recycler view
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    // That's all!

    return rootView;
}

private void startLoaderManager() {
    LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
    loaderManager.initLoader(DEFAULT_MOVIE_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    Log.v("############", "startLoaderManager finished");
}


@Override
public Loader<ArrayList<Movie>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Log.v("############", "onCreateLoader called");
    Uri baseUri = Uri.parse(UrlsAndConstants.DefaultQuery.DEFAULT_URL);
    Log.v("############", "baseUri is "+baseUri.toString());
    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = baseUri.buildUpon();
    Log.v("############", "uriBuilder is "+uriBuilder.toString());
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter(API_KEY_PARAM, API_KEY_PARAM_VALUE);
    Log.v("############", "uriBuilder.toString() is "+uriBuilder.toString());
    String urls = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=4182aa25bab27d06344e404f65c4ae76";
    return new DefaultMovieLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), urls);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<Movie>> loader, ArrayList<Movie> movie) {
    Log.v("############", "startLoaderManager finished");
    if (movie.isEmpty()) {
        Log.v("******************", "movies isEmpty");
        return;
    } else {
        Log.v("############", "movies are"+movie);
        // Attach the mAdapter to the recyclerview to populate items

        mAdapter.setMovieData(movie);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<Movie>> loader) {
    Log.v("############", "onLoaderReset called");
}
}
```

**DefaultMovieAdapter.java**

```
public class DefaultMovieAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<DefaultMovieAdapter.ViewHolder>{

// Store a member variable for the movies
private ArrayList<Movie> mDefaultMovie;
// Store the context for easy access
private Context mContext;
private Movie currentMovie;

// Pass in the movies array into the constructor
public DefaultMovieAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Movie> movies) {
    mDefaultMovie = movies;
    mContext = context;
}

// Easy access to the context object in the recyclerview
private Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}
/*
 Provide a direct reference to each of the views within a data item
 Used to cache the views within the item layout for fast access
 */
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    /*
    Your holder should contain a member variable
    for any view that will be set as you render a row
    */
    public final TextView movieTitleTextView;
    public final ImageView movieTitleImageView;
    /*
    We also create a constructor that accepts the entire item row
    and does the view lookups to find each subview
    */
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        /*
        Stores the itemView in a public final member variable that can be used
        to access the context from any ViewHolder instance.
        */
        super(itemView);
        movieTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_movie_title);
        movieTitleImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_movie_image);
    }
}

@Override
public DefaultMovieAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.item_movies, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DefaultMovieAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Log.v("############", "onBindViewHolder called");
    // Get the data model based on position
    currentMovie = mDefaultMovie.get(position);
    Log.v("############", "currentMovie called is "+currentMovie.toString());
    Log.v("############", "currentMovie's title is "+currentMovie.getMovieTitle().toString());
    /*
    Set item views based on your views and data model
    TextView textView = viewHolder.movieTitleTextView;
    */
    viewHolder.movieTitleTextView.setText(currentMovie.getMovieTitle());
    Log.v("############", "title is :>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+currentMovie.getMovieTitle());
    //ImageView button = viewHolder.movieTitleImageView;
    //viewHolder.movieTitleImageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    String url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/"+currentMovie.getMoviePosterPath().toString();
    Log.v("############", "poster path is :>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+currentMovie.getMoviePosterPath().toString());
    Picasso.with(getContext())
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(viewHolder.movieTitleImageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.v("############", "getItemCount called with size "+ mDefaultMovie.size());
    return mDefaultMovie.size();
}
public void setMovieData(ArrayList<Movie> weatherData) {
    Log.v("############", "setMovieData Called");
    mDefaultMovie = weatherData;
    Log.v("############", "mDefaultMovie is "+mDefaultMovie);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.v("############", "notifyDataSetChanged Finished");
}
}
```

**DefaultMovieLoader.java**

```
public class DefaultMovieLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader {

/**
 * Query URL
 */
private String mUrl;

/**
 * Constructs a new {@link DefaultMovieLoader}.
 *
 * @param context of the activity
 * @param url     to load data from
 */
public DefaultMovieLoader(Context context, String url) {
    super(context);
    mUrl = url;
    Log.v("############", "url is "+mUrl);
}

@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    forceLoad();
    Log.v("############", "onStartLoading called");
}

/**
 * This is on a background thread.
 */
@Override
public ArrayList<Movie> loadInBackground() {
    if (mUrl == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // Perform the network request, parse the response, and extract a list of news.
    ArrayList<Movie> movies = QueryUtils.fetchMovieData(mUrl);
    Log.v("############", "loadInBackground called");
    return movies;
}
}
```

**Note:** The code is available also in a Gist here: https://gist.github.com/rajtheinnovator/4ae0ab873129eff84db68d5645ac64d8

**Edit:**

```
public class QueryUtils {
private static String movieTitle;
private static int movieId;
private static String moviePosterPath;

/**
 * Create a private constructor because no one should ever create a {@link QueryUtils} object.
 * This class is only meant to hold static variables and methods, which can be accessed
 * directly from the class name QueryUtils (and an object instance of QueryUtils is not needed).
 */
private QueryUtils() {
}

/**
 * Query the GUARDIAN dataset and return an {@link Movie} ArrayList to represent a single Movie.
 */
public static ArrayList<Movie> fetchMovieData(String requestUrl) {
    Log.v("############", "fetchMovieData called");
    // Create URL object
    URL url = createUrl(requestUrl);

    // Perform HTTP request to the URL and receive a JSON response back
    String jsonResponse = null;
    try {
        jsonResponse = makeHttpRequest(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //handle exception
    }

    // Extract relevant fields from the JSON response and create an {@link Event} object
    ArrayList<Movie> movies = extractFeatureFromJson(jsonResponse);

    // Return the {@link Event}
    return movies;
}

/**
 * Returns new URL object from the given string URL.
 */
private static URL createUrl(String stringUrl) {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(stringUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        //handle exception
    }
    return url;
}

/**
 * Make an HTTP request to the given URL and return a String as the response.
 */
private static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
    Log.v("############", "makeHttpRequest called");
    String jsonResponse = "";

    // If the URL is null, then return early.
    if (url == null) {
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        /*
        If the request was successful (response code 200),
        then read the input stream and parse the response.
        */
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
        } else {
            //handle exception
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //handle exception
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    return jsonResponse;
}

/**
 * Convert the {@link InputStream} into a String which contains the
 * whole JSON response from the server.
 */
private static String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    if (inputStream != null) {
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            output.append(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    }
    return output.toString();
}

/**
 * Return a list of {@link Movie} objects that has been built up from
 * parsing a JSON response.
 */
public static ArrayList<Movie> extractFeatureFromJson(String jsonResponse) {
    Log.v("############", "extractFeatureFromJson called");
    Log.v("############", "jsonResponse"+jsonResponse);

    // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding movies to
    ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();

    /*
    Try to parse the received jsonResponse. If there's a problem with the way the JSON
    is formatted, a JSONException exception object will be thrown. Catch the exception
    so the app doesn't crash, and handle exception.
    */
    try {
        // Parse the jsonResponse string
        JSONObject movie_json_response = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        Log.v("############", "JSONObject is: " + movie_json_response.toString());
        if (movie_json_response.has("results")) {
            JSONArray resultsArray = movie_json_response.getJSONArray("results");
            if (resultsArray.length() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < resultsArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject movieDetail = resultsArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    if (movieDetail.has("title")) {
                        movieTitle = movieDetail.getString("title");
                    }
                    if (movieDetail.has("id")) {
                        movieId = movieDetail.getInt("id");
                    }
                    if (movieDetail.has("poster_path")) {
                        moviePosterPath = movieDetail.getString("poster_path");
                    }
                    Log.v("############", " title is "+movies + "############ id is"+movieId+" ############ poster path is "+moviePosterPath);
                    movies.add(new Movie(movieTitle, movieId, moviePosterPath));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        //handle exception
    }
    Log.v("############", "Movies returned is: " + movies.toString());
    // Return the list of movies
    return movies;
}
}
```

**Update:**

StackTrace here in the gist: https://gist.github.com/rajtheinnovator/4ae0ab873129eff84db68d5645ac64d8#file-stacktrace-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your QueryUtils class. You are always retrieving element at index 0.
Change from:

```
JSONObject movieDetail = resultsArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

to

```
JSONObject movieDetail = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marcelo, I'm not sure though that how was I getting a correct ArrayList returned from there then.

Comment: Sorry @Marcelo but I can accept only one answer and also I'm unable to upvote because of my low credit. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

Update your parser logic which exist in *QueryUtils*.

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultsArray.length(); i++) {
 Change zeroth index to i
//JSONObject movieDetail =  resultsArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

And I suggest you create a Local variable *currentMovie* instead of Global variable.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DefaultMovieAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
// Use Local variable
Movie currentMovie = mDefaultMovie.get(position);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @rahul , I've tried that already and it doesn't work not even after un-installing and installing the app just now. Anything else you can suggest? Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not on Skype and neither does my broadband allow me enough speed. Can you please still suggest something?

Comment: Please show your code of this block QueryUtils.fetchMovieData(mUrl);

Comment: Ok, I updated that also stack trace is put and you can see that I'm getting enough data and not just a single movie details.

Comment: Check updated answer, your parser logic have an issue.

Comment: @rahulkapoor it is worth mentioning my answer, not just updating yours.

Comment: Thanks @rahul, O don't understand when it got messed up. Probably when I recreated my project when copying from older files. Thanks but I don't understand even now that how I getting a correct ArrayList.

Comment: @MarceloLiberato I didn't see you answer while editing mine. My previous answer was on the basis of suspect, but after asking and checking his parsing logic, it was clear where an issue is.

Comment: @AbhishekRaj You are getting correct size of array list because you are looping correctly but was trying to get data of 0th position.

Comment: @rahulkapoor it's fine, no problem!

Comment: Upvoting yours :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the code above is ok, except that I messed up on handling JSON. As @rahul and@marcelo suggested, the problem was in the for loop inside the method *extractFeatureFromJson* of the class *QueryUtils.java* where I coded:

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultsArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject movieDetail = resultsArray.getJSONObject(0);
//other code
}
```

But the actual lines should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultsArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject movieDetail = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i);
//other code
}
```

The rest of the code above is pretty okay and works fine.